# Getting array out of array having position and length of 2nd array

Tags: php, arrays

Say you have 20 length array `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19];`
and you always need a 13 length array out of this ^ array.

Knowing that I need the number 14 *-but not knowing the index of 14 in the 20-length array-* from this array with having a position 5 on the 13-length array.

```
$number = 14;
$position = 5;
$array = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 13; $i++){
    $array[] = (($number - $position + $i)%20);
}
```

This will print `[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,0,1]`

However this will also print `[-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` instead of `[18,19,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` of the number would be 2 and position 4

Comment: if it does not have an index then it's not an array. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Actually deleted my answer and added it to the question as there's still an error in it. Does my try clarify my question more?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Php sorry, I forgot to add that tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php

$input = range(0, 19);
$position = 4;
$number = 2;

$currentNumberPos = array_search($number, $input);
$fromEnd = array_splice($input, min(0, $currentNumberPos - $position), max(0, $position - $currentNumberPos));
$fromStart = array_splice($input, max(0, $currentNumberPos - $position));
$result = array_slice(array_merge($fromEnd, $fromStart), 0, 13);

var_dump($result);
```

Explanation:

1. array_search will return number position in our array
2. `$fromEnd` is the slice from the end of the array that we will put in front in the result. This will be empty if current number position is greater than desired.
3. `$fromStart` is the slice from the beginning of the array we will take. If current number position is lower than desired then it won't change our input array.
4. Final step is to merge these two arrays and limit length of the result.